# How do you return something in a ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the ActionFilterAttribute in asp.net mvc. What I want to do is check if the users subscription is expired if it is I want to redirect the user to a page if not then do nothing.

But the methods that you can override are all void. So how do I do this? Like I don't even know how to unit test it either since it is void.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is an Authorization Filter:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (...subscriptionExpired...)
    {
        filterContext.Cancel = true;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/user/login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I was hoping to break it up but I guess I can look into that. Why do you still have to set it to Cancel? can't you just redirect?

Comment: I also dont' want to override the OnAuthorization

Comment: @chobo2: why not?? That's the way to do it - why insist on **not** doing it that way? What's the motivation?